# can case object act as a state

Tags: scala, design-patterns, state

My current project is using Java. we push business logics to enum which represents particular state ( New, Registered and so on). In scala, I just wonder that is it a good idea to use case object to act as state ? what is the drawback.

One simple example

```
trait State {
   def read() : Try[String] = {
  Failure(new IllegalStateException("too young to read"))
}
}
case object child extends State

case object young extends State {
  override def read() : Try[String] = {
    Success("young people read book")
  }
}
case object elder extends State {
  override def read() : Try[String] = {
    Success("elder people read book")
  }
}

class Person(state : State) {

   def read() : Try[String] = {
      state.read()
   }
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to make your case classes Uppercase, eg `Child` instead of `child`.

Comment: Check out Akka's [finite state machine](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.1/scala/fsm.html) (FSM) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be and in fact it is pretty common pattern (accompanied with sealed trait by the way), **but** implementation I've seen usually move any actions out of state and use `case objects` as tags that signify current state, alongside with case classes that may store some state data:

```
sealed trait State
case class Connected(messagesProcessed: Long) extends State
case object Connecting extends State
case object Disconnected extends State

def foo() = state match {
  case Connected(count) => "do something"; state = Connected(count + 1) // could be .copy(..)
  case Connecting       => "wait patiently"
  case Disconnected     => "trigger reconnection"
}
```

Reasoning behind using case classes to store data (versus storing it in plain old class fields) is that different states *may* have different sets of variables and with case classes it is easier to comprehend current working set.